# How to print an enumerated list (with the char) without separating the characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been killing my mind to solve the following but i just cannot seem to find the right expression. The code is the following:

```
nameList = ['j', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']
for index, i in enumerate(nameList):
    print(___________ , sep='x', end = '')
```

The thing that needs to be done is to fill in the gap with an expression between the index and `i`, that will end up printing `0j1a2m3e4s`. I have tried multiple things but I just seem to be stuck right here.

Any help or tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to _format_ `index` and `i` — ask G....e for _python format_ — moreover, I'd recommend to use the name `letter` (or similar) in place of `i`.

Comment: Another possibility consists in simply printing your variables using the null string 
 `""` as the separator used by `print` (the correct syntax is already shown in the template you're following...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`enumerate`** with `format`:

```
nameList = ['j', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']
for index, i in enumerate(nameList):
    print('{}{}'.format(index, i), end = '')

# 0j1a2m3e4s
```

Or without `format`:

```
nameList = ['j', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']
for index, i in enumerate(nameList):
    print(str(index) + i, end = '')
```

Comment: This does work but i am not allowed to change the format. All i need is to find an expression between index and i, such as index*i (which is not correct, but you get the idea).

Comment: Use `print(str(index) + i, end = '')`.

Comment: Also upvote other answers if you find them helpful. They are equally good. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the `enumerate`, then use the empty string `''` to separate those characters.

```
from itertools import chain

nameList = ['j', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']
print(*chain.from_iterable(enumerate(nameList)), sep='')
# 0j1a2m3e4s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `string.join` statement to achieve this:

```
print "".join(str(index) + i for index, i in enumerate(nameList))

>>> 0j1a2m3e4s
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just

```
print(''.join('{}{}'.format(index, i) for index, i in enumerate(nameList))
```

or even better in python 3.6

```
print(''.join(f'{index}{i}' for index, i in enumerate(nameList))
```